# Minimum force required so that cylinder just touches the ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, spring

While studying for weekly examination I came across this problem in mechanics
the question is as follows-
"Two wedges with a section in the form of an isosceles right-angled triangle were placed on a horizontal surface with a wide edge down, and pulled together by two springs with a stiffness of *k= 100 N/m*
each. A cylinder was placed on the wedges, it moved the wedges apart and stopped in balance when there was a gap ***h* =1 cm** between it and the base. A slowly increasing force was applied to the right wedge, as a result of which the system began to move, and the cylinder began to gradually, without hesitation, fall. At what minimum force will it touch the surface at the base of the structure? All bodies
have the same mass. There is **no friction**.

refer the image for diagram , if not able to view the image
[click here](https://im.ge/i/rptyly)

[image: Please refer image for diagram]

My main concern is how to solve this problem in the most efficient manner , I used work energy theorem to solve but I am not sure if my answer is correct , my answer is as follows-

> *in order to find the initial relation between the mass and normal reaction between the let's use the free body diagram in equilibrium condition, then I used the relation between the x - axis displacement of wedge and y - axis displacement of cylinder and found out that if there is a movement by y cm in y direction the spring will expand by length 2*y cm , and then  by using Conservation of energy I proceeded to find the force.*

Is there a more efficient way to find the answer more importantly is my solution correct also please share alternate solutions if possible .

for my rough workings refer [here](https://im.ge/i/rpytdp)

Comment: The small part of the solution you have shown, the geometry of height changes related to spring length is correct. For the rest my first idea would not be to consider conservation of energy, but forces caused by the acceleration. Maybe you give some more of your workings, how you tried to solve?

Comment: sure its really rough please try to bear with me [link](https://im.ge/i/rpytdp) @kricheli

Comment: I don't think energy analysis is the way to go. Consider, for example, if the cylinder has zero mass?  Then $F$ that's required would just be the $F$ that applies sufficient counterforce to the spring to open it the right distance for the cylinder to touch the ground. In fact, I'll just leave it here as a hint: First solve the zero mass cylinder, then what changes when the cylinder has mass? Just an extra force in the $F$ direction is all that's relevant.